# How do I unlink my YouTube account from my Gmail account?

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management

My YouTube account has been automatically linked to my Gmail account, but I want to keep my YouTube account separated from my Gmail account. I heard that the feature to unlink accounts was available. Is it? If yes, how do I access it?

I have tried [phwd's solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1695/354) and it's telling me that my account was permanently linked. Is their any way to get around this?

Comment: It looks like the only way to have separate Gmail and YouTube accounts is to have two separate Google accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want this [Unlink YouTube and Google Accounts](http://www.youtube.com/my_account_unlink)

It is available via  [Account](http://www.youtube.com/account) -> [Manage Account](http://www.youtube.com/account#manage/status) -> [Unlink YouTube and Google Accounts](http://www.youtube.com/account#manage/unlink)

However, if you signed up for YouTube after May, 2009, you can't unlink them.

Comment: Also whatever anyone tells you *deleting your account* will not solve the problem.

Comment: As of August 2019, there is not an option to unlink your account, even if it was created before 2009.

Comment: This is not correct. I have an account from the past. But there is no option to unlink whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

According to [Use your Google Account for Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/69961?hl=en), as of September 8, 2017, users need a Google Account to use Youtube.

Regarding the old Youtube accounts, those aren't Google Accounts, the referred above official help article says:

> Some [older, unused YouTube accounts](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/3219097#ts=3309345) (created before May 2009) might not be part of a Google Account. They need to be added to one before they can be used.

If you want to change the owner of a Personal Channel, you could move it to a Brand Channel. For further details see [Move YouTube channel to Brand Account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283?hl=en).

Comment: From https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2663685, the linked help article on the blog post, "​Keep in mind that you do need a Google Account to sign into YouTube."

Comment: Oh dang.  I remember reading that Youtube would stop requiring a Google account to sign up, and figured that must have been implemented by now, but I guess I misunderstood.  But if you create a second Google account for Youtube, it's not going to let you be logged into both in the same browser, is it...

Comment: @endolith: It's possible to be signed in into several Google Accounts at the same time, actually we have a tag for related questions: [tag:google-multi-login]

Comment: The tag info includes the link to the official help article :)

Answer (score 2):

**As of 2021** it is possible to delete the youtube service from your google account

These are the steps to follow:

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/data-and-personalization
2. Delete a service or your account
   [image: s2]
3. Delete a service
   [image: s3]
4. Delete the youtube service
   [image]