# How Can I Delete My YouTube Account?

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, google-account, account-management

My school email address is not `@gmail.com`, however, it is managed by GMail, so I log into a special school log-in and it takes me to my email with the familiar GMail tools and GMail inbox.

Unfortunately, it linked itself to a youtube account. **I want to either delete this YouTube account or unlink it.**

However, as you can see, there is no unlink button nor are there delete account options. I also tried this question : [How do I unlink my YouTube account from my Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/how-do-i-unlink-my-youtube-account-from-my-gmail-account) and followed the link to [Unlink Youtube and Google Accounts](http://www.youtube.com/account#manage/unlink), but it doesn't do anything and simply redirects me back to my Manage Account page.

[image: Manage Account Page]

Comment: It sounds like you have a temporary YouTube account. Try completing the username and channel details. Then I think you will get the option to close your account.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/), log in with your Gmail account and from there you can manage your Google account, including unlinking YouTube accounts.

--EDIT--

From Google dashboard find Youtube and click on Profile Setup, then Manage Account, and under that you will have a button to close the youtube account, see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any options to unlink any accounts from that page, can you provide the next step?

Comment: @rlb.usa See edit

Comment: I can't press that button because I don't have it. See my screenshot. The entire `Close Account` section isn't there.

Comment: +1 @rlb.usa It's there as I just used it a few days ago. It takes some time for Google to perpetuate updates to all of it's users accounts. Try clearing your cache to see if that makes a difference.